# Selenium: How to avoid using thread.sleep while locating dynamically populated lookup field options

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a dynamic lookup salesforce component on the webpage.

[image: ![Dynamic Lookup salesforce component]

```
<input lightning-basecombobox_basecombobox="" id="input-19" type="text" role="textbox" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search undefined..." maxlength="255" aria-autocomplete="list" required="" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input" aria-controls="dropdown-element-19" data-position-id="lgcp-1000001" aria-describedby="help-message-18">
```

After I type first 3 letters, the options are displayed dynamically and I have to select the option.
This is the HTML code for the component after selection:

```
<input lightning-basecombobox_basecombobox="" id="input-19" type="text" role="textbox" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Bandra West Branch" maxlength="255" required="" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-combobox__input-value" aria-controls="dropdown-element-19" data-position-id="lgcp-1000007" aria-describedby="help-message-18" readonly="">
```

And this is my Selenium-Java code for selecting the value:

```
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(newLoanObj.txtBranch()));        
    newLoanObj.txtBranch().sendKeys(data.get("Branch"));
    Thread.sleep(2500);
    newLoanObj.txtBranch().sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
    newLoanObj.txtBranch().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Now, the problem is the dynamically populated options takes time to populate and I can not get the locator for the options displayed after sending the key values. Thus I cant use wait for the options to appear. So I am forced to use thread.sleep in this case. So my script fails sometime if the options are not populated within the specified time. So what is the way out to avoid using thread.sleep and still wait till the options are populated after send keys and continue script execution without failures?

Comment: Consider not selecting from the drop down- type in the full value that is required. Without knowing your application configuration i would assume that lookup value and select is OOTB functionality tested by the vendor, unless you've customised it there's no value in testing it.  While you're (probably) testing as the end user, this isn't the purpose of the test; If you must test this lookup funciontality work, create a specific test for it then if it has a 10s wait it doesnt matter as it's only once . I would suggest you think about cutting the corner, type the full value  :-)

Comment: Actually answering you question(!) Can you share the HTML source for that dropdown box?   - you're already using expected conditions,  instead of DOWN + ENTER,  do something like... drop this inside your webdriverwait wait.until( ... : `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath( "//*[contains(text(),'Branda West Branch][1]"))`   - the `[1]` and the `*` are the weak points as i don't know what else is in your page so it's a bit of a guess

Comment: can you share url  here ?

Comment: @RichEdwards: Solution provided by you worked

Comment: String strDynamicXPath =  "//*[contains(text(),'" + data.get("Branch") + "')]"; wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(strDynamicXPath)));
newLoanObj.txtBranch().sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
newLoanObj.txtBranch().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Comment: @Huzefa - not bad for a guess without seeing the html! ;-)    -  i don't think you need the keys.down either - since you're waiting for the objec to appear, you can find it - so just click it ... i'll post an answer and you can give it a go

Comment: @RichEdwards: Tried without Keys.ARROW_DOWN does not work. This is required in this case since after sending the keys in the textbox, I need to go to the 1st option to select it.

Comment: @RichEdwards: your next comment is the more appropriate answer. Consider changing your answer to that.

Comment: @Huzefa thanks for feeding back - it's updated as you suggest - i really thought it would work but it was a guess based on a screenshot afterall :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(summarised from the comments on the question)

Without seeing the html, the following is an approach that works:
(good job @Huzefa)

```
String strDynamicXPath = "//*[contains(text(),'" + data.get("Branch") + "')]"; wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(strDynamicXPath)));
newLoanObj.txtBranch().sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN); 
newLoanObj.txtBranch().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

The xpath finds any relative element with `//*` that contains the required text and returns the first instance of it with `[1]`. It's wide sweeping and could do with being more accurate but if it works then it's an option.

It's worth a note that @Huzefa tried to access the object without the keys, but this was unsuccessful. Updated the answer to remove an alternative code block as it didn't work.

---

Also worth consideration here is the testing approach.: (updated a little it)

> Consider not selecting from the drop down - type in the full value that
> is required. Without knowing your application configuration I would
> assume that lookup value and select is Out-Of-The-Box (OOTB) functionality tested by
> the vendor, unless you've customised it there's no value in testing
> it. While you're (probably) testing as the end user, this isn't the
> purpose of *this* test; If you must test the lookup functionality,
> create a specific test for it then if it has a 10 seconds wait it doesn't
> matter as it's only a one-off activity. I would suggest you think about cutting the
> corner, type the full value

Answer (score 0):

Please use explicit wait for this. Code in selenium 4 looks like this

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(20));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocatedBy(By.xpath(".....");

// use the element
```